# Access 2010: data rows as column headings?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2013.

I need to display AND EDIT a grid of data based on three tables:

```
UnitID    UnitName
1         Unit1
2         Unit2
3         Unit3

ProdID    ProdName
1         Furniture
2         Food
3         Other

UnitID    ProdID      Forecast
1         1           10
1         2           20
1         3           30
2         1           40
2         2           50
2         3           60
3         1           70
3         2           80
3         3           90

so it looks like:
             Unit1   Unit2   Unit3
Furniture      10      40      70
Food           20      50      80
Other          30      60      90
```

Furthermore, the query must be editable (user should be able to enter his forecast data).

Any idea how to do this in Access 2010? I've looked into pivots and crosstab queries, but they use aggregate functions and thus aren't editable... but in my case, the source of the data is unambiguous so an editable option should exist? Anyone has an idea how to get the data in editable format?

Thanks!
Jur.

Comment: You cannot edit MS Access crosstabs, but you can cheat, for example http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs,_forms_and_updating

Comment: This is a very very classic setup.

Comment: As I understand it, you're supposed to edit the data in the lower subform, right?

Comment: An option would be to use a C# / WinForms as front-end, and to use an unbound flex grid there. At least that's my preferred way to go.

Comment: @SQLPolice you do not need C# to have unbound controls.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp table and fill it with the data from your crosstab query. Use that table as the source for a form, which will be editable. In the beforeupdate event of the form, add code to update the original source table.

Comment: Come on, editing a temp table is most awful and worst solution ! *[I never downvote]*

Comment: That's a bit harsh. While I do think the OP is using the wrong approach, it does provide an intuitive, workable solution.

Comment: I admit you are right. I also have no better solution to provide. At least not within MS Access. Didn't mean to be harsh, but I was just shocked and freezing to my bones because I know how awful it is to program the event handling of such a table/form. But there is no better solution within Access. Therefore, I personally would create a C# frontend with a (unbound) flexgrid control. You have then also better navigation possibilites.

Comment: Agreed, a .NET FE would be an elegant solution, but I have a feeling that it would not be an option for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

distributing any kind of exe is not an option due to security measurements in the client's environment (they can run Office and little else). So I'm going for the temp table option anyway... any pointers for a template solution to modify to my needs?

Thanks again!
Jur.